# How to properly display MJPEG snapshot from CCTV in PHP

Tags: php, html, snapshot, mjpeg

I have a IP CCTV camera which support MJPEG. I would like to display image in HTML (from PHP script) together with other data.

I know that I can get a screenshot from the camera using:

```
http://username:password@<servername>/Streaming/channels/1/picture
```

however when I am using this simple html code image is not always displayed:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <IMG id="myImage" SRC='http://username:password@192.168.0.20/Streaming/channels/1/picture'>
  </body>
</html>
```

On Microsoft Edge, it is not possible even to login to camera. 
On Firefox works fine. 
On Chrome camera is logged however image is not displayed.

So the question is how I can get image in HTML or better in PHP to display it on the page. I prefer to use PHP because I want to add more data to page, like temperature etc.

Also will be nice to refresh the image, but this can be done in AJAX later.

Answer (score 2):

Use a second PHP script to retrieve the image and point the `<img>` tag to that.  It's possibly because the page you're displaying the image on uses HTTPS while the camera only supports HTTP.  Proxying through PHP will allow it all to appear to come from the same source and PHP will handle the HTTP authentication, which will avoid any of your browser compatibility problems.

`<IMG id="myImage" SRC='currentimage.php'>`

currentimage.php:

```
<?php
$crl = curl_init('http://<servername>/Streaming/channels/1/picture');
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$contents = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $contents;
?>
```

To save on server load and allow it to handle more traffic, you could also cache the last-retrieved image to a file for 5-10 seconds, but that's a separate problem to solve.

Comment: doesn't work for me, I am not getting any picture using this method

Comment: And you've replaced `<servername>` as well as `username` and `password`?  What happens when you visit currentimage.php in a browser?  Do you get an error?

Comment: yes, of course :-) When I am accessing currenimage.php I can't see any image nor anything else

Comment: Do you have errors set to display in PHP?  You may have to comment out the Content-type line in order for it to display properly as your browser would otherwise try to interpret that error as an image.

Comment: Hi omnichad, I am not getting any error. However I found also a similar script which works ok in my case. Please take a look below. Thank for for your help and contribution.

Comment: Looks like I accidentally left out `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); `.  Updating my answer.  Unless `$useragent` is set, I doubt it's having any effect, but some embedded devices might require it.

Answer (score -1):

This code seems to work fine for me:

```
<?php
while (@ob_end_clean()); 
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://<servername>/Streaming/channels/1/picture'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password'); 
// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $output; 
// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch); 
?>
```